# Request a JSON with pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to request a JSON file (from Google Maps API) with a complex architecture to get all `lat` and `lng`. Please, find here the JSON Schematic :

```
root                                                                            
 |-- geocoded_waypoints: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- geocoder_status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- place_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- types: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- routes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- bounds: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- northeast: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- southwest: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- copyrights: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- distance: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- duration: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- end_address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- end_location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- start_address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- start_location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- steps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- distance: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- duration: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- end_location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- html_instructions: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- maneuver: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- polyline: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- points: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- start_location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- travel_mode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- traffic_speed_entry: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- via_waypoint: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- step_index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- step_interpolation: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- overview_polyline: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- points: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- summary: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- warnings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- waypoint_order: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is my function to get `lat` and `lng` datas :

```
def getTraceGps(json_file, spark):
   #Lecture du fichier route
   sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
   df=sqlContext.read.json(json_file, multiLine=True)
   df.printSchema()
   df.createOrReplaceTempView("Maps")
   df.select(df["routes.bounds.northeast.lat"],   df["routes.bounds.northeast.lng"]).show() #IT WORKS
   df.select(df["routes.legs.steps.end_location.lat"],df["routes.legs.steps.end_location.lng"]) #WRONG
   results.show()
```

Here is the LOG :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`routes`.`legs`['steps']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''steps'' is of string type.;;
'Project [routes#1.legs[steps].end_location.lat AS lat#19, routes#1.legs[steps].end_location.lng AS lng#20]
+- AnalysisBarrier
  +- Relation[geocoded_waypoints#0,routes#1,status#2] json

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:120)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3295)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1307)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't understand why the first `df.select` works and not the second one. 
Maybe because `steps` contains several objects. 
I tried a lot of queries before but I was wrong.

Where does the problem come from ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is kind of cryptic, but notice `legs` is an array type. Becuase it's an array you must choose a specific element using bracket notation (like `legs[1]`)

I haven't seen `IntegralType` in any documentation but it is part of `spark.sql` internals. It's just an internal datatype to represent arrays and the like, see

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cba69aeb453d2489830f3e6e0473a64dee81989e/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/AbstractDataType.scala

Comment: But if I need to choose an index to select a row, do a sql request doesn't make any sense. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.